# Publishing VSTO add-in using MSBuild gives error: The "SignFile" task failed unexpectedly. System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, vsto, teamcity

I am trying to publish a VSTO add-in for Word using MSBuild on a TeamCity build server without Visual Studio. I've done the stuff from these two blog posts:

http://kentb.blogspot.com/2008/08/building-vsto-projects-without-visual.html
http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2011/02/msb3147-could-not-find-required-file-on.html

My build file is my Visual Studio solution and my target is "publish". ClickOnce publishing in Visual Studio 2013 on my development machine works fine.

But on the build server, I get this:

> [SignFile] C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets(612,
>   9): error MSB4018: The "SignFile" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   path1 at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2, String
>   path3) at
>   Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Deployment.ManifestUtilities.SecurityUtilities.GetPathToTool()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Deployment.ManifestUtilities.SecurityUtilities.SignPEFile(X509Certificate2
>   cert, Uri timestampUrl, String path, ResourceManager resources,
>   Boolean useSha256) at
>   Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Deployment.ManifestUtilities.SecurityUtilities.SignFile(X509Certificate2
>   cert, Uri timestampUrl, String path) at
>   Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Deployment.ManifestUtilities.SecurityUtilities.SignFile(String
>   certThumbprint, Uri timestampUrl, String path) at
>   Microsoft.Build.Tasks.SignFile.Execute() at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__20.MoveNext()

I have no idea what this means or how to fix it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question as this might help someone in future.

I found that it's because that version of the SignFile task requires signtool.exe, which I did not have installed. I installed the Windows SDK with all options ticked, and it was installed and my publish task now works. I am not sure which of the options it comes under, but I think it's not the .NET one as I already had that installed.

Comment: According to http://www.unawave.de/windows-7-tipps/4-gb-patch-selber-machen/makecert-und-signtool-besorgen.html its in "Windows Native Code Development" -> "Tools"